# Coded UI RPF images in bin/debug folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I use Coded UI test framework in my project. I use this test automation as dynamically, so i write test without macros.
I noticed if an error occurred during the execution in my test, for example not found a control, a picture was captured about the screen.
These pictures were stored in bin/debug folder.

I attached a picture about them, all of name started with "RPF".

[image]

I did not find anything about them.

How can i disable this screen capturing function?

---

Thanks for advance,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the value of "EqtTraceLevel" according to your need.

Please refer following URL for detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159363.aspx

And if you are using MTM to run your test cases using codedUI refer following URL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286596.aspx

Please write back if you need any more help.

Sam

Comment: Hi! I searched all *.config file which name contains "QTAgent.exe".
So, i modificated "QTAgent.exe.config",  "QTAgent_40.exe.config", "QTAgent32_40.exe.config" contents etc.
I set "EqtTraceLevel" value to 0 and added EnableSnapshotInfo and EnableHtmlLogger element to appSettings node the value of false. The result was the same: if an error occured during execution of test, a picture was captured.